# Sending notification using application on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

How can I send notification using application on Facebook? As I know this function FB blocked several monthes ago, but there are still some applications, which requests are notified me using FB notifications. So how can I make the same? In graph API there is nothing said about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest way to send "notifications" is through the Request 2.0 implementation. They are no longer referring to them as notifications. Facebook now decides if the user will get a notification in addition to a request or not.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/

Comment: Is there any way we can impact on this "decision"? Who is making this decision - their server automatically or their team manually?

Comment: A big factor is the response rate to actions your app takes. If there are a lot of "hides" for stories posted, Facebook assumes your app is spammy and will reduce the distribution. If users like your app and content, Facebook will do it's best to get your content noticed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of doing this, it is extremely hard to find in the documentation and it doesn't work very well (and I think it might even be slightly buggy).

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#requests

for some reason it is under the requests section rather than the notifications section.

Here is the code example on the page, I tested this and it doesn't result in a red notification icon appearing on the globe notification thing - it just increments the number on the application bookmark on the left hand side of your home page. I imagine this is an extremely inneffective way of getting a message to your users. If you have an app that is not a canvas app (like a page tab app) this actually does nothing as you don't have a bookmark icon for the application.

```
<?php 

  $app_id = YOUR_APP_ID;
  $app_secret = YOUR_APP_SECRET;

  $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?" .
    "client_id=" . $app_id .
    "&client_secret=" . $app_secret .
    "&grant_type=client_credentials";

  $app_access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

  $user_id = THE_CURRENT_USER_ID;

  $apprequest_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/" .
    $user_id .
    "/apprequests?message='INSERT_UT8_STRING_MSG'" . 
    "&data='INSERT_STRING_DATA'&"  .   
    $app_access_token . "&method=post";

  $result = file_get_contents($apprequest_url);
  echo("App Request sent?: ". $result);
?>
```